# Получить курсы валют из интернета php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Как получить курсы валют с других сайтов? Нужны именно значения, а не `iframe`-таблички. Пробовал вставить на сайт сначала `iframe`, а с него получить значение, но не получилось, и мне кажется, что есть способ попроще.

Comment: google [курсы валют цбр API](https://www.google.ru/search?q=курсы+валют+цбр+API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может подойдет этот вариант? Хоть в `xml`, хоть в `JSON` https://api.privatbank.ua/api-info/exchratenbu.html

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите обсуждение [здесь](https://toster.ru/q/7088)

Резюмируя, у банков есть публичный API, часто сами банки описывают,как им пользоваться.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще попробовать [Курсы валют и не только от rbc.ru](http://export.rbc.ru/expdocs/free.cb.0.shtml?USD)
Заполни форму один раз руками, как тебе захочется, нажми ok, скопируй получившуюся ссылку из браузера, что бы имена полей увидеть, благо там GET все получается. По мимо курсов там есть некоторые другие биржевые показатели в свободном доступе.

Вывод данных текстовый, с указанным тобой разелителем, разбить эти строчки split сразу в массив не проблема.

Например `http://export.rbc.ru/free/cb.0/free.fcgi?period=DAILY&tickers=NULL&lastdays=0&separator=TAB&data_format=BROWSER&header=1`

даст курс всех валют на день запроса, разделитель полей табуляция. Если в ссылке в конце сделать `header=0` то не будет заголовка, который программе разбора мешать будет.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте бесплатный API для получения курсов валют в банках и обменниках Украины из сайта Kurstoday

https://github.com/pavlovich-app/KursToday-API

Есть возможность получать курсы валют всех самых популярных банков Украины а также [курс валют в обменниках Киева](https://kurstoday.com.ua/ru/kiev), [Харькова](https://kurstoday.com.ua/ru/kharkiv), [Днепра](https://kurstoday.com.ua/ru/dnipro), [Одессы](https://kurstoday.com.ua/ru/odessa), [Львова](https://kurstoday.com.ua/ru/lviv), [Луцка](https://kurstoday.com.ua/ru/lutsk), [Ровно](https://kurstoday.com.ua/ru/rivne), [Ивано-Франковск](https://kurstoday.com.ua/ru/ivano-frankivsk), [Сумы](https://kurstoday.com.ua/ru/sumy), [Кривой Рог](https://kurstoday.com.ua/ru/kryvyi-rih) и много других городов Украины

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]